# Best possible RAID configuration for 2x1TB and 2TB hard drives

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

I've been trying to set up a server for business and purchased a server to that end.

Due to lack of space for the number of users, I tried to increase the space by adding more hard drives.

I have a Two 1TB disks and 1 2TB disk. All disks are Seagate disks but the 2TB is NAS disk.

I've been trying to configure these in a RAID configuration on Windows 2016 Server Essentials, on HP ProLiant ML10 Gen9.

The in built software on the server said that RAID 5 is best and it automatically went ahead with the configuration. But upon finishing the server seems to have slowed down a lot.

Data being accessed from the server is a lot slower than before.

What should be the ideal way to configure these disks?

Comment: How about a raid1 for both your 1tb drives, and a nice backup with the 2tb one ? (just in case, you never know what can go wrong)

Answer (score 3):

AVOID AVOID AVOID RAID 5/50 - this is repeated on serverfault every week if not every few days, it's dead and dangerous technology that can kill your data. We can bore you with the maths behind this if you want but please only use R1/10 or R6/60. That said you have a proper mix of disks and sizes there, given you're using W2016 you could just create one storage spaces pool and carve out R1 logical disks from that.

Answer (score -1):

[RAID1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1).

Because:

- Your 3 disks are not the same size, so really you can only use the 2x1TB disks.

  (or buy another 2TB disk and create 2 RAID1 arrays)
- It is the best performance-wise with 2 disks
- It is the fastest recovery-wise

RAID5 and RAID6 are considered less viable with high disk sizes (1TB and above).

Use RAID1 and RAID10 when possible.